# Android Studio WebView Div Hide

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have a webpage like this

```html
<div id="home" class="cvitae-section slider sliderStyle7 active"> 
 <div class="cvitae-container"> 
  <div class="slider-content"> 
   <div class="box-container" >  
    <p class="name">  HAMZA KAVAK</p>
    <p class="designation">  &lt; Web Developer /&gt; </p>  
   </div> 
  <img src="img/slider/7-image.png" class="image" alt="Slider"> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to partially view a webpage on webview android and remove some div element from the webpage.

```js
package com.example.hamteknocom;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    WebView webV ;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // view start
        webV = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webV.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('box-container')[0].setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");");
        webV.loadUrl("http://hamzakavak.com/");

        // view stop

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

url :  **webV.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('box-container')[0].setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");");**

Comment: What's the question? Are you having problems with that code?

Comment: Yes, Div is not hidden

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Java Docs >>> readingURL

```
    String someString;
    URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yahoo.openStream()));

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        someString = someString + inputLine;

    in.close();
```

Now you have it in string and you can work with that it...

When you will be done, you should just convert your edited string to html string:

```
String yourHtmlString = Html.toHtml(someString);
```

**!!!** ...but consider not all html tags working on android **!!!**

Comment: please mark it as correct answer if it was usefull... thank you :)